# Function acting on lists arguments

Tags: r, list, function

I am trying to reduce the following code using a function, but I the result is somewhat unexpected. If I use this code

```
A <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(4,5,6))
B <- data.frame(x = c(7,8), y = c(1,2))
Lst <- list(A, B) 
names(Lst) <- c('A','B')
idx <- c('A', 'B')

Lst[['A']]['name'] <- 'A' 
Lst[['B']]['name'] <- 'B'
```

I get the output

```
> Lst
$A
  x y name
1 1 4    A
2 2 5    A
3 3 6    A

$B
  x y name
1 7 1    B
2 8 2    B
```

as expected and requested. I wanted to use a function, instead, in order to make the result more general, for further applications, using this code:

```
bad.lst <- mapply(function(lst,x) {
  lst[[x]]['name'] <- x
  return(lst)
}, Lst, idx)
```

and the result is unexpectedly

```
  A           B          
x Numeric,3   Numeric,2  
y Numeric,3   Numeric,2  
A Character,3 Character,2
```

Is there any way to fix the second code to get the same outcome as in the first code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
Lst1 <- Map(cbind, Lst, name = names(Lst))
```

as `mapply` can return a matrix because by default it uses `SIMPLIFY = TRUE`

```
mapply(cbind, Lst, name = names(Lst))
#     A         B        
#x    Numeric,3 Numeric,2
#y    Numeric,3 Numeric,2
#name factor,3  factor,2
```

Instead, if we change `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`

```
mapply(cbind, Lst, name = names(Lst), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
#$A
#  x y name
#1 1 4    A
#2 2 5    A
#3 3 6    A

#$B
#  x y name
#1 7 1    B
#2 8 2    B
```

Comment: This is absolutely perfect and elegant! Thank you so much.